# How to prevent toggle effect when an inside anchor is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an accordion effect using the code bellow and it works. The problem is that when I click on the link inside the article it closes the content and doesn't open the link. How do I prevent this from happening? Thanks ahead.

http://jsfiddle.net/vinicius5581/Lrpwojyg/

HTML

```
<section>
   <ul class="booklist">
     <li>
         <a>Article Name 1</a>
         <article>                        
              <p><content</p>
              <img class="left" src="myimage"/>
              <p>more content</p>
              <a href="http://www.google.com">This link shouldn't close article</a>
          </article>
     </li>
     <li>
         <a>Article Name 2</a>
         <article>                        
              <p><content</p>
              <img class="left" src="myimage"/>
              <p>more content</p>
              <a href="http://www.google.com">This link shouldn't close article</a>
          </article>
     </li>
     <li>
         <a>Article Name 3</a>
         <article>                        
              <p><content</p>
              <img class="left" src="myimage"/>
              <p>more content</p>
              <a href="http://www.google.com">This link shouldn't close article</a>
          </article>
     </li>
   </ul>
</section>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("li").click(function(){
  $(this).find("article").slideToggle().end().siblings("li").find("article").slideUp();   
});
```

CSS

```
.booklist>li>article{
     display:none
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using following code

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings("article").slideToggle()
       .closest("li").siblings("li").find("article").slideUp();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrpwojyg/4/)

Or use **[`e.stopPropogation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** to prevent click event on `a` tag

```
$("li").click(function(){
     $(this).find("article").slideToggle().end().siblings("li").find("article").slideUp();   
}).on('click','article a',function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrpwojyg/8/)

Comment: .stopPropagation was a good method. This works as it should. Voting up.

Answer (score 1):

this is the code i gave you, you could have just answered the other post. Target the `a` instead

```
$(".booklist li a").click(function(){

  $(this).siblings("article").slideToggle().closest("li").siblings("li").find("article").slideUp();   
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrpwojyg/6/)

Comment: You right and I used this solution as a matter of fact. For the community I though those would be two different topics and that's why I created the new question. Double thanks to you. Voting up.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 $("li > a").click(function(){
         $(this).parent().find("article").slideToggle().end().siblings("li").find("article").slideUp();   
    });
```

instead http://jsfiddle.net/Lrpwojyg/9/

Comment: The problem with this is that if I have an <a> in the article, it wont  open the link and it will close the article. Still voting up as I didn't specify this on my question but I would like to see how could you get around this.